# Why isn't this javascript returning the expected code?

Tags: javascript, string, variables, logging, operators

```
let myName = 'vincenzo';
if (myName !== String) {
console.log('this is not a string');
} else if (myName.length % 2 === 0){ 
console.log(even);
} else if (myName.length % 2 !== 0){
console.log(odd);
}
```

can anyone explain why this only returns "this is not a string"? shouldn't it return "even"? I am not sure where I am going wrong

Comment: Hint: `typeof`.

Comment: Hint: `typeof myName !== 'string'`

Comment: You should avoid specifying the only other logical possibility in your `else if`. As in `if (x == 1)` then the else is *automatically* the logical inverse, as in `if (x != 1)`. Don't specify the obvious.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to clean up this code:

```
function determine(str) {
  if (typeof(str) !== 'string') {
    console.log('this is not a string');
  } else if (str.length % 2 === 0) { 
    console.log('even');
  } else {
    console.log('odd');
  }
}

determine('vincenzo');
```

Comment: @iota Working on it.

Answer (score 0):

```
const determinfun=(MyName)=>{
if (type of MyName !== String) {
console.log('this is not a string');
} else if (MyName.length % 2 === 0){ 
    console.log('even');
} else if (MyName.length % 2 !== 0){
console.log('odd');
}
}

determinfun('vincenzo');
```

Please use the **type of operator**  type of MyName !== String